# compiling visual C++ code in linux?

Tags: linux, visual-c++, gcc, opencv, cmake

i have a visual C++ program which performs image matching. I am using openCV. I am looking to run the exe on a linux server. But i dont know how to compile visual C++ code in linux?

Can anyone plz help me in this regard . .  .

Comment: See, Visual C++ is just Microsoft's compiler for C++... Do you mean you want to know how to compile C++ code in Linux? GCC can do that, but you will probably have more work porting the code than just compiling.

Answer (score 5):

If you did things smartly while writing the C++ code in MSVC, you isolated all platform-dependent code (i.e., Microsoft extensions to C++ and uses of Windows-only libraries) from the rest right from the start, and know exactly where to do the modifications to make it run on Linux as well.

Unfortunately, your question hints at this being your first attempt at cross-platform coding, and in that case, you probably littered Microsoft-isms all over your code, and have to pick through them one by one. Start the compiler, have a look at its error messages, and go from  there. Good luck, it will be a pain, but also a very valuable lesson for your next project.

(I'm not finger-pointing at MSVC here. The very same is true for people who litter their code with GNU-isms and then want to have it compile on MSVC...)

The usual construct looks like this:

```
#if defined( _MSC_VER )
// Microsoft version
#elif defined( __GNUC__ )
// GCC version
#else
#error Platform / compiler not supported.
#endif
```

**Edit:** In case it is not obvious, the idea is to keep the ifdef'ed code above at an absolute minimum. Use typedef's, forwarding functions (i.e., log() to use either Unix or Windows logging), or - if all else fails - macros. *Don't* use the above all over the code, isolate it in a few header / implementation files, kept in a separate source folder.

You will also want to familiarize yourself with Makefiles (shameless plug: [Makefile tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile)) or [CMake](https://cmake.org/), because MSVC project files don't work on Linux (obviously).

Comment: After familiarizing with Make, You could check out CMake. It has fairly easy syntax and allows to generate project files for Visual, Eclipse, Make and some other. And it's configuration files are very lightweight (plain text files)

Comment: @Link: Personally I couldn't care less about Visual, Eclipse etc., so I can neither second your recommendation nor say anything against it. Make did always float my boat, even in several environments not related to compiling C source.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once. After 25 years developing I do this almost unconsciously, but I have never seen it so well described. I also was unaware of the _MSC_VER tag and have been struggling with using a bunch of other defines to distinguish MinGW from MSVC compilation. Unfortunately MinGW (or at least the MSys flavour I am using) varies slightly from Posix and requires some Win32 APIs.

Answer (score 2):

There's also winelib and stuff. Point your build system to using winegcc/wineg++ as your compiler, and go for it. It can compile a fairly large subset of windows programs. This should be a good option if all you need is to get one or two programs to work.

Comment: The description of winegcc suggests it is a MinGW replacement. My experience of MinGW is that it cannot compile MSVC targetted code, especially MFC. I think what the OP and I both need is a way to turn an MSVC solution file into executable code on Linux. Running MSVC under Wine doesn't work.